# Difference between creating new object and dependency injection

Tags: java, object, dependency-injection

What is the difference between creating a new object and dependency injection? Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well,
creating a new object is as explicit as it can get - you create a new instance of the desired class.

Dependency injections is a mechanism that provides you with references where you need them.
Imagine a class that represents a connection pool to your database - you usually only have one instance of that class. Now you need to distribute that reference to all the classes that use it.
Here is where Dependency Injection comes in handy - by using a DI framework such as Spring you can define that the one instance of your pool will be injected into the classes that need it.

Your question itself is not easy to answer since the creation of an object and dependency injection can't be compared that easily...

Comment: How is that different than using a Singleton?

Comment: @Radu a Singleton is a design pattern that restricts the number of instances of a specific class to a maximum of one. So the creation of the instance is part of the pattern implementation. The singleton doesn't get injected into the places where you need it, that's what you need dependency injection for.

Comment: How is that single instance of the class that gets "magically" instanced and distributed better than calling a SingletonClass.getSingleInstance() is my question. This dependency injection looks redundant for me if you only have 1 instance, just use the singleton pattern.

Comment: @Radu you can switch the instances that dependency injection gives you. For instance in unit tests you get a subclass that's designed to work with the unit tests. Also who said that the injected instances are singletons?

Comment: "you usually only have one instance of that class." - which is true. The only benefit I see over singletons is you can garbage collect that single instance when not needed and reinstance it when needed.

Comment: @Radu The difference is very important. `SingletonClass.getSingleInstance()` gives you an instance of the concrete `SingletonClass`. You may use that in many locations of your code. DI usually injects an interface `ISingletonClass` that matches the `SingletonClass` signature. You determine which concrete implementation gets used in the single spot where you create the DI. So you can reuse your code without changing it with different implementations of `ISingletonClass`. Eg. in unit testing or on different platforms.

Answer (score 47):

Well, they're not exactly comparable. You will always have to create a new object by instantiating a class at some point. Dependency injection also requires creating new objects.

Dependency injection really comes into play when you want to control or verify the behavior of instances used by a class that you use or want to test. (For Test Driven Development, dependency injection is key for all but the smallest example).

Assume a class Holder which requires an object of class Handle. The traditional way to do that would be to let the Holder instance create and own it:

```
class Holder {
    private Handle myHandle = new Handle();
    public void handleIt() {
        handle.handleIt();
    }
}
```

The Holder instance creates myHandle and no one outside the class can get at it. In some cases, unit-testing being one of them, this is a problem because it is not possible to test the Holder class without creating the Handle instance which in turn might depend on many other classes and instances. This makes testing unwieldy and cumbersome.

By injecting the Handle instance, for example in the constructor, someone from the outside becomes responsible for the creation of the instance.

```
class Holder {
    private Handle myHandle;

    public Holder(Handle injectedHandle) {
        myHandle = injectedHandle;
    }

    public void handleIt() {
        handle.handleIt();
    }
}
```

As you can see the code is almost the same, and the Handle is still private, but the Holder class now has a much loser coupling to its outside world which makes many things simpler. And when testing the Holder class a mock or stub object can be injected instead of a real instance making it possible to verify or control the interaction between the Holder, its caller and the handle.

The actual injection would take place at some other place, usually some "main" program. There are multiple frameworks that can help you do that without programming, but essentially this is the code in the "main" program:

```
...
private Handle myHandle = new Handle(); // Create the instance to inject
private Handler theHandler = new Handler(myHandle); // Inject the handle
...
```

In essence, the injection is nothing more than a fancy `set` method. And of course, you can implement the injection mechanism using that instead of in the constructor like the simple example above.

Comment: I just logged to upvote this, it's way better than the accepted anwser and explain thing is a proper way.

Comment: But how the `injectedHandle` is being initilized outside our control when we create a `Holder`? What if there are more parameters, how it knows how to initilize them, or notto initialize at all?

Comment: @Yoda, added a description of how to do the actual injection. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great Explanation, hope this gelps many devs who are learning more about design patterns

Answer (score 24):

Of course, both create objects. The difference is in who is responsible for the creation. Is it the class that needs its dependencies or a container like Spring for example, which wires the component's dependencies? You configure the dependencies in a separate(typically XML) configuration file.

It is really a separation of concerns. The class says I need this, this, and this component to function properly. The class doesn't care how it gets its components. You plug them into the class with a separate configuration file.

To give you an example let's consider having a shopping class that needs a payment module. You don't want to hardcode which payment module will be used. To achieve this you inverse the control. You can change the used payment module with a few keystrokes in the configuration file of the container. The power is that you aren't touching any Java code.

Comment: This is an excellent answer as I am also trying to understand that when we design class how do we decide that whether we should be injecting it as a dependency or creating a new instance of the object inside the class.

Answer (score 5):

Dependency injections adds a layer of configurability into your application. In the sense, when you hard code object construction, you need to re-build and re-deploy your app, but when you use dependency injection, you can re configure the XML and change the behavior without re-building and re-deploying. There are a large variety of use cases where this can save a lot of tie and effort.

Answer (score 3):

When using an inversion-of-control container to perform dependency injection, the container creates the objects, and not the developer. This is done so that the container can "inject" these objects into other objects.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the following question may also give the answer you are looking for: Why is the new operator an anti-pattern? Well, the simple answer is that using the new operator may create a hidden, inaccessible dependency within the containing class. This makes testing the containing class more difficult because it involves testing the hidden dependency at the same time (barring MOCK frameworks of course). However, you can avoid this situation by not using the new operator and injecting the dependent object instead. This also has the following advantages:

- For test purposes you can inject a different object.
- The resulting containing class is more reusable because it can support different implementations of the dependent object.

Comment: Better late than never I hope!