# Why is Dependency Injection better than instantiation in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, constructor, angular2-services

I am trying to understand how DI works in Angular 2.

In simple words, DI means to inject the service that our components might need, rather than creating the service or instantiating the service in the component class.

> (*If this is correct, then I feel Angular 2 [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-providers) is a
>   bit misleading as it uses the terminology of 'creating instances'
>   while explaining 'injector provider'*)

Now, technically this boils down to :- **use constructor instead of new**

But why, what are the advantages of using a constructor over new? Are there any example/resources online that I can follow...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386889/difference-between-creating-new-object-and-dependency-injection some info at previous question

Answer (score 0):

The best advantages I can think of, is that DI suits very well with unit testing. Imagine you want to test a class which its functionality triggers another unit that you want to test its functionality in separate scenarios. In this case, if you use DI, you can create a dummy object instance which will just serve that scenario alone and inject that so that the unit you are testing can be isolated. This mechanism could not be achieved if you created that instance in the testing class itself.