# how to mock failure of FileReader

Tags: typescript, jasmine, filereader

I have a function which creates a `FileReader`. In that function I also set the `load` and `error` event handlers

```
handleFileSelect(files:ArrayLike<File>){
...
      let reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = this.handleReaderLoaded;
      reader.onerror = this.handleReaderError;


      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

I want to unit-test that `handleFileSelect` correctly sets the error handler and that the error handler (`handleReaderError`) gets called if `FileReader` fails. But I can't figure out how to make the `FileReader` fail.

The spec I have written so far is

```
fit('should call error handler when file doesn\'t get loaded successfully', (done) => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;

    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");
    /*
    File reader will load the file asynchronously.
    The `done` method of `Jasmine` makes `Jasmine` wait
    When handleReaderError is called, call a fake function and within it call done
     */
    spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'handleReaderError').and.callFake(function(event:FileReaderProgressEvent){
      console.log("called fake implementation of handleReaderError ",event);
      expect(event.type).toEqual("abort");
      done();
    });

    newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);
//I SHOULD SIMULATE FILEREADER ERROR HERE BUT HOW??

  });
```

Comment: Were you able to find a good solution for this?

Comment: I got reference of the `FileReader` and use `dispatchEvent` to simulate error `reader.dispatchEvent(new Event('error'));`. Did you try the answer provided by mixth below?

Comment: I saw it, but could not fully understand it. How did you reference `FileReader` from within your function?

Comment: I have a similar but different question I asked here - would your solution work in my case too?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806605/test-filereader-onerror-handling

Answer (score 2):

It was already said that we can mock `readAsDataURL` method and dispatch the error event from it. But your reader is a local variable in the function `handleFileSelect`. In order to access the reader, we can mock the `FileReader` constructor and get control of the created file reader instance.
Here I use [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) for mocking:

```
// in your test:
...

// This is the reader instance that we have access
const reader = new FileReader()

// We throw an error in readAsArrayBuffer method of that instance
reader.readAsArrayBuffer = () => {
  reader.dispatchEvent(new Event('error'))
}

// Now make the constructor return our instance
sinon.stub(window, 'FileReader').returns(r)

// Now make your calls and assertions
...    

// Don't forget to restore the original constructor at the end
window.FileReader.restore()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `reader`'s behaviour is calling `onerror` when `readAsDataURL` fails, this should do:

```
spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader, 'readAsDataURL').and.callFake(() => {
    newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader.onerror();
});
```

Since this will be running as a synchronous call, you can simplify the assertion at the end of the test (following a triple A) like this:

```
// Arrange
const newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent, 'handleReaderError');
spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader, 'readAsDataURL').and.callFake(() => {
    newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader.onerror();
});
let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");

// Act
newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);

// Assert
expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleReaderError).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'abort' });
```

But I don't recommend expecting the parameter passes to the function, `event.type`, because it is **the specification of another unit** that we are not currently testing. (we are testing `newPracticeQuestionComponent` not the behaviour of `reader` calling an error with an event)

---

Mocking the behaviour of `reader` might not be the best way. It depends on what you want to test against the unit.

In case we want to go extremely independent, `newPracticeQuestionComponent` should know nothing about `reader`'s behaviour even the callback error, the only thing this unit should know is to set the `onerror` callback, you can just assert that you set the `onerror` of reader correctly.

```
// Arrange
const newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader, 'readAsDataURL');
let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");

// Act
newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);

// Assert
expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader.onerror).toBe(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleReaderError);
```

I am no master about testing, but it seems to be pros and cons writing tests like the above and below examples upon many factors.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. `reader` is local variable of function `handleFileSelect`. I cannot do `newPracticeQuestionComponent.reader`.

Comment: How do you create the `reader` then? You can mock them in that way.

Comment: for the time being, I am returning the instance of the reader from `handleFileSelect` and then use `reader.dispatchEvent('error')` to simulate the error. It is not the best workaround because my code gets both `load` and `error` events but at least I am able to test that `error` works

Comment: From what I understand, testing should influence how we design softwares but not bending the software itself to make testing easier. When this `reader` is initialized? For example, if `newPracticeQuestionComponent` gets `reader` by calling `ReaderService.get()` then we can create a mock `reader` from there.

Comment: I agree and it was not my preference either but I couldn't find an alternative. `reader` is created in `handleFileSelect`. The workflow is to read a file selected by the user (using `input` html tag) and then show it as a thumbnail. I don't really need an instance of the reader outside the `handleFileSelect` function.

Comment: In that case, I usually use dependency injection technique to loose the coupling. I may add another class to do the `reader` creation instead of the unit under test. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387013/3635881) explains it quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a typescript file and a severity to be set depending on the success of reading an inputs file from disk:

```js
enum Severity
{
  NONE = 'none',
  ERROR = 'danger',
  OK = 'success'
}

private jsonFile: File | undefined = undefined;
private severity: Severity = Severity.NONE;

protected changeFileSelection(): void
{
  this.jsonFile = this.input.files?.[0];

  const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = () => this.load(JSON.parse(fileReader.result as string));
  fileReader.onerror = (error: ProgressEvent<FileReader>): void => {
    this.severity = Severity.ERROR;
    console.error(error);
  };
  this.severity = Severity.OK;
  fileReader.readAsText(this.jsonFile, 'UTF-8');
}
```

You can test the onerror call in Jasmine as follows:

```js
it('should handle file read errors', () => {
  const emptyFile: File = new File(['{}'], 'filename.json');
  component['jsonFile'] = emptyFile;
  const dataTransfer: DataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
  dataTransfer.items.add(emptyFile);
  input.files = dataTransfer.files; // @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182158/959484
  const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(fileReader);
  spyOn(fileReader, 'readAsText').and.callFake((): void => {
    expect(component['severity']).toEqual(component['Severity'].OK);
    fileReader.dispatchEvent(new Event('error'));
  });

  component['changeFileSelection']();

  expect(component['severity']).toEqual(component['Severity'].ERROR);
});
```

Note, that the `readAsText` call must be after the positive Severity result you want to have in case of a successful read. But in this test case, the outcome will be negative due to simulated Error while reading.