# Why inject FormBuilder instead of declaring it

Tags: angular

I noticed that the constructor for `FormBuilder` is a default empty constructor.

```
export class FormDI {
   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

   private buildForm() {
      let form = this.fb.group({...});
   }
}

export class FormNoDI {
   private buildForm() {
     let form = new FormBuilder().group({...});
   }
}
```

The above classes both have a perfectly fine FormBuilder, so why is it good practice to use dependency injection for these type of classes instead of just declaring them like a variable?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386889/difference-between-creating-new-object-and-dependency-injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the default empty constructor has to do with it... the reason DI is a good practice here is the same as the reason it's a good practice anywhere.

Specifically, if you don't use DI but instead use `new FormBuilder`, then you are tightly coupled to the specific `FormBuilder` implementation your code imports - so, if nothing else, it's harder to write tests that are insulated from `FormBuilder`.

By using DI, you allow that you can pass in any object that will "pass for" a `FormBuilder` (from an interface standpoint), so your test code can easily pass in a mock instead of a real FormBuilder (to force specific behavior for specific test cases, or just to avoid the test depending on "proper" behavior of a real FormBuilder).

Note that mocks, like anything, can be overused, and whether you would *want* to supply an alternate implementation depends on circumstances.  But by using DI, you have the choice.